# I want to know why use BUF_SIZE = 1024

Tags: c, tcp

I studiying TCP/IP programming

I have a one question.

Under the servercode

```
    #incldue <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    
    #define BUF_SIZE 1024
    #define wating_room_size 5
    #define OPSIZE 4
    
    void error_handling(char *message);
    int calculat(int opnum, int opnds[], char operator);
    
    int main(int argc, int argv[])
    {
        int serv_sock, clnt_sock // 서버 소켓과 클라이언트 소켓
        int opinfo[BUF_SIZE]; // 받아오는 메세지 즉, 숫자들
        int result, opnd_cnt, i; // result 는 연산의 값, opnd_cnt 는 받아온 숫자의 수, i 는 반복문에 이용
        int recv_len, recv_cnt; // recv_len 받아오는 데이터의 총 길이, recv_cnt 는 받아오는 데이터의 길이
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, clnt_addr;
        socklent_t clnt_addr_size;
        
        if(argc != 2)
            error_handling("Usage : %s <PORT> \n", argv[0]);
        
        serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        
        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
        
        if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_Addr)) == -1)
            error_handling("bind() error");
        
        if(listen(serv_sock, wating_room_size) == -1)
            error_handling("listen() error");
        
        clnt_addr_size = sizeof(clnt_addr);
        
        
        
        for(i = 0; i < wating_room_size; i++)
        {
            opnd_cnt = 0;
            clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_addr, &clnt_addr_size); 
            read(clnt_sock, &opnd_cnt, 1); 
            
            recv_len = 0;
            while((opnd_cnt*OPSIZE+1)>recv_len)
            {
                recv_cnt = read(clnt_sock, (int*)opinfo, BUF_SIZE-1); 
                recv_len = recv_cnt + recv_len; 
            }
            
            result = calculate(opnd_cnt, (int*)opinfo, opinfo[recv_len-1]); 
            wirte(clnt_sock, (char*)&result, sizeof(result));
            close(clnt_sock);
        }
        close(serv_sock);
        return 0;
    }
    
    int calculate(int opnum, int opnds[], char op) // 반복횟수, 숫자, 연산자.
    {
        int result = opnds[0], i;
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                for(i=1; i<opnum; i++)
                    result += opnds[1];
                break;
            case '-':
                for(i=1; i<opnum; i++)
                        result -= opnds[1];
                break;
            case '*':
                for(i=1; i<opnum; i++)
                        result += opnds[1];
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    void error_handling(char *message)
    {
        fputs(message, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(1);
    }


client code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define RLT_SIZE 4
#define OPSZ 4
void error_handling(char *message);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sock;
    char opmsg[BUF_SIZE];
    int result, opnd_cnt, i;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr;
    
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s <port> \n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    serv_adr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2])); 
    
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr)) == -1) 
        error_handling("connect() error");
    else
        puts("connected....");
    
    fputs("Operand count : ", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &opnd_cnt); 
    opmsg[0]=(char)opnd_cnt;
    
    for(i=0; i<opnd_cnt; i++)
    {
        printf("Operand %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", (int*)&opmsg[(i*OPSZ)+1]);
    }
    fgetc(stdin);
    fputs("Operator: ", stdout);
    scanf("%c", &opmsg[opnd_cnt*OPSZ+1]); 
    write(sock, opmsg, opnd_cnt*OPSZ+2);
    read(sock, &result, RLT_SIZE);
    
    printf("Operation result : %d \n", result);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

void error_handling(char *message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

it's a sample code.
i can't understand why set buf_size 1024byte..

```
recv_cnt = read(clnt_sock, (int*)opinfo, BUF_SIZE-1);
```

what is mean BUF_SIZE-1 ?? 1023 byte

```
read(clnt_sock, (int*)opinfo, BUF_SIZE-1);  --- A sentence
```

i know A sentence accepts value from the client.

but why use BUF_SIZE - 1 ???

may be that's mean take out operator?

if you can't understand my question , and please you describe what is mean that A sentence.

P.S 혹시 한국말을 쓸줄 안다면 한국말로 설명부탁드립니다.

Comment: **"why `1024`?"**: a nice round number (in the point of view of the binary computer: `1024 = 0b10000000000`) with no other reason to be chosen other than `1000` or `873` or anything large(ish) enough really. **"why `1024-1`?"** Maybe, just guessing, to allow for an extra `'\0'` to be added to data and transform it to a *bona-fide* string.

Comment: Higher buffer sizes have the disadvantage that they cost extra memory and lower buffer sizes have the disadvantage that they may have to be filled more often, so they are less efficient. Therefore, the author probably decided that 1024 would be an appropriate compromise.

Comment: Because they felt like it.